# kmalloc-256 seems taking most of the memory resource. How can I free this?

Tags: linux, memory

I have a Linux instance (Amazon Linux `Linux ip-xxx 4.9.20-11.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1`) which runs Jenkins. It occasionally stops working because of the lack of the memory needed for a job.

Based on my investigation with `free` command and `/proc/meminfo`, it seems that `Slab` is taking up most of the memory available on the instance.

```
[root@ip-xxx ~]# free -tm
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       7205        779          0         19        310
-/+ buffers/cache:       6876       1108
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:        7985       7205        779

[root@ip-xxx ~]# cat /proc/meminfo | grep "Slab\|claim"
Slab:            6719244 kB
SReclaimable:      34288 kB
SUnreclaim:      6684956 kB
```

I could find the way to purge `dentry` cache by running `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, but how can I purge `kmalloc-256`? Or, is there a way to find which process is using `kmalloc-256` memory space?

```
[root@ip-xxx ~]# slabtop -o | head -n 15
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 26805556 / 26816810 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 837451 / 837451 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 85 / 111 (76.6%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 6696903.08K / 6701323.05K (99.9%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.25K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
26658528 26658288  99%    0.25K 833079       32   6664632K kmalloc-256            
 21624  21009  97%    0.12K    636       34      2544K kernfs_node_cache      
 20055  20055 100%    0.19K    955       21      3820K dentry                 
 10854  10646  98%    0.58K    402       27      6432K inode_cache            
 10624   9745  91%    0.03K     83      128       332K kmalloc-32             
  7395   7395 100%    0.05K     87       85       348K ftrace_event_field     
  6912   6384  92%    0.02K     27      256       108K kmalloc-16             
  6321   5581  88%    0.19K    301       21      1204K cred_jar
```